# Laravel translation without domain

Tags: php, laravel, internationalization

When using Laravel's i18n feature, I need to create a file for each locale and for each translation 'group'. For example, a messages.php file would return an array of generic messages, and a validation.php would return an array of validation messages, and both those files would exist for each locale I have set. This means I have a `lang/en/messages.php` as well as a `lang/it/messages.php`, each with the correct translated string for each specified key.

Is it possible to have a "generic" translation file that doesn't require to specify a group when calling `Lang::get()`? What I would like to do is to be able to call `Lang::get("MyString")` instead of `Lang::get("group.MyString")`.

Comment: So you mean that if there is no `dot` you would like to get data from `messages` file?

Comment: That would work, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I need to modify Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php

The solution is to take a domain by default (in this case, messages.php) and then add to the phrase ($id) the domain if there is not dot.

```
function trans($id = null, $parameters = [], $domain = 'messages', $locale = null)
{
    if (is_null($id)) {
        return app('translator');
    }

    if (strpos($id, '.') === false) {
        $id = "messages." . $id;
    }

    return app('translator')->trans($id, $parameters, $domain, $locale);
}
```

Comment: You should not modify files at the vendor folder directly.